# Fetching User's Event List from Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I have to fetch the event list of the current user logged in my app in Android and I'm using this code to extract the list:

```android
  String fqlQuery = "SELECT eid, name, pic, creator, start_time FROM event WHERE eid IN " + " (SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid = me() LIMIT 25)";
        Bundle params = new Bundle();
          params.putString("q", fqlQuery);
          Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
          Request request = new Request(session,
              "/fql",                         
              params,                         
              HttpMethod.GET,                 
              new Request.Callback(){         
                  public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                      Log.i(TAG, "Result: " + response.toString());
                  }                  
          }); 
          Request.executeBatchAsync(request);                 
      }
```

but I'm always getting blank result set. Please let me know what am I missing here. I'm new to this and trying to learn from facebook developers guide.

Permission that I'm using for my app:

- Default Activity Privacy: Public
- User & Friend Permissions: user_events friends_events
- Auth Token Parameter: queryString

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not where you set your permissions, this is for the App Center. There is a note right at the top of that page.

**Use these settings to enter the set of permissions your app requires when displayed in App Center**

You need to add the permissions scope within your Android code

> Android login uses the setReadPermissions and setPublishPermissions on the LoginButton class.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/#adding

For example in the Android Login Tutorial

```android
LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.authButton);
authButton.setFragment(this);
authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("user_events", "friends_events"));
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/login-with-facebook/#step3

Comment: Thanks! I just figured out this permission method. Yes now I'm setting through code.